# Does every element in a well-ordered set have a successor element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am currently reading Faticoni's *The Mathematics of Infinity* (2nd edition), and I think there is an error in his writing. He defines a well-ordered set by the following:

> **Definition 6.1.1** Let $A$ be a nonempty set. We say that $A$ is a well-ordered set if it satisfies the following two properties:
>
> 1. $A$ satisfies the Trichotomy Property. That is, given $x, y \in A$ then $x$ and $y$ satisfy exactly one of the following options, $x < y$, $y < x$ or $x = y$.
> 2. $A$ satisfies the Minimum Property. That is, each nonempty subset of $A$ contains a unique least element. Equivalently, to each element $x \in A$, there is a unique element $x^+ \in A$ such that (given $y \in A$ such that $x < y$, then $x^+ \leq y$.) We call $x^+$ the successor of $x$.

The problem is that in condition 2, I don't think the two properties are equivalent; there can be a greatest element in the set which has no successor. Later, he argues that the set $A = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, b, c\}\}$ is not a well-ordered set because $\{a, b, c\}$ does not have a successor element. But I think this is wrong since $A$ satisfies both the Trichotomy Property and the Minimum Property so $A$ should be well-ordered? I feel like this is such a big error that reading this book further won't be possible without resolving it. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your set $A$ is well-preserved under inclusion.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Yeah that's also something concerning. The usual definition of a well-ordered set that I know is that it is a set with a total order whose non-empty subsets have least elements. But I am having difficulty showing that the definition in the book and the usual one are equivalent.

Comment: Condition 2 is not well written. You can take $x^+=x$, which satisfies the given condition, and in tbe case where $x$ has strict upper bounds, the minimum of the strict upper bounds. The problem is not necessarily with a maximum, as you can let $x^+=x$. Or in fact, *anything*, since the implu ation would be satisfied by vacuity.

Comment: Transitivity is presumably implicit in the use of $<$ as a partial order symbol?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yeah, that is true; we can just define the successor element of the max $A$, if it exists, to be itself since the statement would be vacuously true anyway. That's why I don't get why he said the set $A$ in the example is not a well-ordered set.

Comment: My point is that the claim is *definitely* incorrect, because of the uniqueness clause. In $\mathbb{N}$, under the usual order, you can define $x^+$ as *either* $x$ or as $x+1$, and both will have the given property, so the successor, as defined, is not "unique", so $\mathbb{N}$ would not satisfy the alternative definition. And under the usual definition of "well-ordered", any finite totally ordered set is well-ordered, though he could be restricting the definition to infinite sets. This is just wrong.

Comment: The equivalence comes by taking the least element of the set of elements greater than $x$ as the successor if this is non-empty. If the set of elements greater than $x$ is empty then there will be no $y \gt x$ so any element will do as the successor (as identified by @ArturoMagidin), and in this case unless $x$ is the unique element in the set, the successor is not uniquely defined by the property. It is a poor definition.

Comment: @MarkBennet: I agree that this is the intended equivalence. But look at the definition: what prevents defining $x^+=x$ in *every* case? If the set of elements greater than $x$ is nonempty, then both $x$ and the least element of the set of elements greater than $x$ satisfy the condition "for all $y$, if $x\lt y$ then $x^+\leq y$", so there is no uniqueness ever.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, you are right: I did say it was a poor definition. It would need to add $x\lt x^{+}$ included to give uniqueness in the non-empty case. And if it ends up suggesting that finite sets cannot be well-ordered, that would be unhelpful - even if (given the title) only infinite sets were in contemplation. It is easy to forget how important good definitions are until a case like this comes along.

Comment: @MarkBennet: And even if we add the clause $x\lt x^+$, then $\mathbb{Z}$ would be "well-ordered" under the "equivalently" clause.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Clearly I am too tired to be writing comments at the moment.

Comment: @MarkBennet: Everything you said was right. I am emphatically agreeing with you, and pointing even more ways this is a mess. ;-)

Comment: This definition is a big red flag to go find a better book.

Comment: @EricWofsey I wish I could! This book is not rigorous at all and has plenty of other errors too. However, I need to write a set of notes on this particular book as a final assignment for one of my courses, so I can't just get rid of it. I am also reading Naive Set Theory by Halmos, and that book is a much better book than this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming $\lt$ is meant to represent a strict order (irreflexive and transitive), then the definition is only correct if you delete everything from "Equivalently"  onwards in clause 2. That part is not just wrong, it is *really* wrong...

First: finite totally ordered sets are well-ordered  under the usual definition, but the author apparently does not want to consider finite totally ordered sets as well-ordered. That's not necessarily a deal breaker, but it is definitely idiosyncratic, at best.

Second: It is clear that the desired "equivalence" is supposed to come from defining $x^+$  to be the least element of $\{y\in A\mid x\lt y\}$. However, this set can be empty even in infinite well-ordered sets: consider a well ordered set of the form $\mathbb{N}\cup\{*\}$, where we order the natural numbers as usual, and let $n\lt *$  for  every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This is well-ordered, and the set $\{y\in A\mid *\lt y\}$ is empty.

Well, that need not be an obstacle:  we can just define $*^+=*$, since the condition "for all $y$, if $*\lt y$  then $*\leq y$" is satisfied.

Third: But this shows a third problem:  if we define $x^+=x$ for any $x$, then this satisfies the given condition; but so will  the least element of $\{y\in A\mid x\lt y\}$  when the set is not empty, so the element $x^+$ will not be unique as required. For example, in $\mathbb{N}$, both $0^+=0$ and $0^+=1$ have the property that if $0\lt y$, then $0^+\leq y$.

Fourth. We *could* try to fix the "equivalently" clause by adding that $x^+$ would be strictly larger than $x$ when $x$ is not the maximum, and equal to $x$ otherwise; that would fix the problems outlined above. It could also be fixed if the defining property of $x^+$ were a biconditional: $x\lt y$ if and only if $x^+\leq y$ whenever $x$ is not the maximum element of $A$, and $x^+=x$ if $x=\max A$.  **But** that is still incorrect: consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with its usual order, and define $n^+=n+1$ for every integer. This set is trichotomic, and every element  has an immediate successor, but is not well-ordered.

So this (incorrect) definition is a mess, even if we restrict it to infinite sets.

You need to delete "*Equivalently, to each element $x\in A$, there is a unique element $x^+\in A$ such that (given $y\in A$such that $x\lt y$, then $x^+\leq y$). We call $x^+$ the successor of $x$.*"

Instead, add the following additional nomenclature:

> If $A$ is well ordered and $x\in A$, then if the set $\{y\in A\mid x\lt y\}$  is not empty, we define $x^+$ to be its least element, and call $x^+$ "the successor of $x$".

Comment: "the author apparently does not want to consider finite totally ordered sets as well-ordered" I think the author not merely doesn't want to consider finite sets, but also bounded ones.

Comment: @Acccumulation but even so restricted, his claimed equivalence is no equivalence.